# whats the maximum voltage that can be given to a capacitor

Tags: capacitor

i have a 10uF capacitor so what is the maximum voltage that can be connected across it? please explain in high school level terms

Comment: The capacitance has absolutely nothing to do with the maximum voltage that can be applied to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet of the capacitor can tell you this. Alternatively, many larger capacitors have their rated voltage printed on them.

Edit: [an introduction to capacitors from Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/capacitors), which may be helpful for you.